# Can using be used to type alias an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, typedef, using

I'm not sure I've worded this properly since this is a bit of an odd situation.
Basically I've found some code like this:

```
template<class T>
struct X { typedef T Type; };

template<class T>
struct X<const T[]> { typedef T Type[]; }
```

And I was in the process of changing the `typedef`s to use the C++11 `using` type-alias syntax when I realised this doesn't seem to work for the second example.

i.e. it isn't possible to do:

```
template<class T>
struct X<const T[]> { using Type[] = T; }
```

Why is this? Is this an 'oversight' by the standards comittee?

Comment: Maybe you mean `using Type = T[];` ?

Comment: @M.M If `using Type = T[];` is the same as `typedef T Type[]` then that qualifies as an answer. I just checked and that does seem to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
using Type = T[];
```

which defines that `Type` has the type "array of unknown bound of `T`".