# Fixed size array alias with "using" syntax

Tags: c++

Consider the following typedef:

```
typedef int int_array_of_size_4[4];
```

Is there an equivalent with the newer "using" syntax? If yes, what is it?

EDIT: This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013243/can-using-be-used-to-type-alias-an-array), since that was about aliasing an array of unknown bound.

Comment: Strictly speaking the answer to your question is: yes. :P I'm assuming what you're really after is "what is the equivalent syntax"

Comment: You can get the type of a type-alias defined with `typedef` by just removing the type-alias name. It means that your `int_array_of_size4` have the type `int[4]`. That's basically how you translate from `typedef` to `using`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can using be used to type alias an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013243/can-using-be-used-to-type-alias-an-array)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
using int_array_of_size_4 = int[4];
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5vUfwTQPixreNyaT)